# Finding minimal distance between unsorted and sorted lists

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, language-agnostic

Let A be a list and S a sorted list of the same elements. Assume all elements are different. How do I find a minimal set of "moves" (`move X before Y (or end)`) that turns A into S?

Examples:

```
A = [8,1,2,3]
S = [1,2,3,8]

A => S requires one move: 
   move 8 before end

A = [9,1,2,3,0]
S = [0,1,2,3,9]

A => S requires two moves:
   move 9 before 0
   move 0 before 1
```

I prefer javascript or python, but any language will do.

Comment: How about `A = S`? Works in I guess every modern programming language where a unsorted and a sorted list have a common base class.

Comment: So you can move an element where ever you like, without a penalty? (Typically, your first example takes 4 moves: shift all elements to the right (3 moves) and place 8 in the end (1 move)). If indeed you can move everything around, you are looking for the [Longest increasing subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence).

Comment: @MartinMeeser The aim isn't making `A` sorted but computing the minimum number of moves that would make it sorted.

Comment: @Heuster: for the purposes of this question, let's assume all moves have the same cost.

Comment: @thg435 I just updated my comment. You want to find the longest increasing subsequence. The number of moves is the length of the array minus that number.

Comment: @Heuster: so, one move per an "out-of-order" element? Looks right, but I want to find all moves, not only their count.

Comment: Not sure if this is optimal solution, but the problem can be reduced to a shortest path problem where `source=A` and `target=S`, with the unweighted graph that contains all permutations and an edge is a  -possible move. Complexity of solution will be `O(n^d)` using BFS, or `O(n^(d/2))` using bi-directional BFS - where `d` is the minimal number of 'moves' needed.

Comment: @amit the size of the graph will grow really fast - we have `n!` nodes. There is a far better performing solution of the problem(have a look at my answer below).

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev You don't need to generate the entire graph - you generate what you need 'on the fly', only the  nodes you traverse, which is around `2*n^(d/2)` using bi-directional search. I do believe a better solution exist following Heuster's claim - but it requires proof.

Comment: thg435 you need to list the moves and not only their number, right? I will try to include a complete solution with code in the next few days.

Comment: Please have another look at my answer. I have added far greater detail in it.

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to finding the best sorting algorithm?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This problem is equivalent to [longest increasing subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) problem.

You will have to define a comparison operator `less`. `less(a, b)` will return `true` if and only if `a` is before `b` in the target sequence. Now using this comparison operator, compute the maximum increasing sub sequence of the source sequence. You will have to move each element that is not part of this sub sequence (otherwise the sub sequence will not be maximum) and you can move it exactly once(moving it to its target position).

EDIT: As requested by amit here is my proof to the statement above:
Lets we denote the target sequence `B` and lets denote the source sequence `A`. Let `n = |A|` and let `k` be the length of the longest increasing sequence as described above.

- Let's assume it is possible to reach `B` from `A` with less moves than `n - k`. This means that at least `n - k + 1` elements from the `A` will not be moved. Let s<sub>1</sub>,s<sub>2</sub>,...s<sub>m</sub> be the set of elements that are not moved. From the assumption we know that `m > k`. Now as these elements have not moved, than their relative position with respect to each other can not have changed. Thus the relative positions of all this elements in the target sequence `B` is the same as the one in `A`. Therefor the operator less(s<sub>i</sub>, s<sub>j</sub>) as defined above should be true for any `i`, `j`. But if this is true then s<sub>1</sub>,s<sub>2</sub>,...s<sub>m</sub> is increasing sequence and as `m > k` this leads to a contradiction with the assumption that k is the length of the longest increasing sequence.
- Now lets show an algorithm to reach `B` from `A` by moving all elements but the ones that are part of the longest increasing sequence. We will move the elements in the order they appear in B. We will not move elements that are part of the longest increasing sequence. If the current element is the first one in B, we simply move it to the beginning of the sequence. Otherwise we move the current element right **after** the position of the previous element in B. Note that this element may either be the previous element we've moved or an element from the longest increasing sequence. Note that at each step when we are about to move element with index `i`, all elements with index `1, 2, ...i-1` will already be with correct relative positions with respect to each other.

EDIT: adding some code to make the answer clearer. I don't feel an expert in javascript so feel free to correct or criticize my solution.

Let's define a function `transform(a, s)` that takes two parameters - lists a and b as described in the statement. First I will create a map `positions` that maps each element in `a` to its position in s:

```
var positions = {};
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
  positions[a[i]] = i;
}
```

Now that I have this array I can define a helper function less as described in my answer above. Less will take two values `a` and `b`(and the helper map I just created) and return true if and only if `a` is before `b` in `s`(the target list):

```
function less(a, b, positions) {
  return positions[a] < positions[b];
}
```

Now I will not describe how can we find the maximum increasing subsequence in `a` with respect to that comparison operator. You can have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2631726/812912) for detailed explanation how to do that. I will simply assume that I have a function defined:

```
function max_increasing_subsequence(a, positions)
```

That returns the maximum increasing subsequence in `a` with respect to the comparison operator `less` as defined above (using `positions`)as a list. I will use your second example to illustrate what we have so far:

```
A = [9,1,2,3,0]
S = [0,1,2,3,9]
```

The values in positions will be as follow:

```
positions = { 0 : 0,
              1 : 1,
              2 : 2,
              3 : 3,
              9 : 4}
```

And the result of `max_increasing_subsequence(a, positions)` will be `[1, 2, 3]`. By the way if there may be repeating elements in `a` it may be better to return indices instead of the elements from `max_increasing_subsequence`(in this particular example the difference will not be visible).

Now I will create another helper map to indicate which are the elements included in the maximum increasing subsequence:

```
var included = {};
l = max_increasing_subsequence(a, positions);
for (var i = 0; i < l.length; ++i) {
  included[l[i]] = true;
}
```

Now you can finish up the solution with a single iteration over `s`. I will add a special case for the last element to make code easier to understand:

```
if (!(s[s.length - 1] in included)) {
  console.log("Move" + s[s.length - 1] + " at the end");
}
for (var i = s.length - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
  if (!(s[i] in included)) {
    console.log("Move" + s[i] + " before " + s[i + 1]);
  }
}
```

Please note that in the solution above I assume that each time you log a new command, you log it with respect to the ordering of the array `a` right after all previous commands have been executed.

So in total I believe transform should look something like this:

```
function transform(a, s) {
  var positions = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    positions[a[i]] = i;
  }
  var included = {};
  l = max_increasing_subsequence(a, positions);
  var included = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < l.length; ++i) {
    included[l[i]] = true;
  }
  if (!(s[s.length - 1] in included)) {
    console.log("Move" + s[s.length - 1] + " at the end");
  }
  for (var i = s.length - 2; i >= 0; --i) { // note s.length - 2 - don't process last element
    if (!(s[i] in included)) {
      console.log("Move" + s[i] + " before " + s[i + 1]);
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this code makes my answer more clear.

Comment: can you prove correctness of this approach? Though I think it is correct, I still want to be certain of it.

Comment: @amit in fact I have proven it mostly experimentally. I have passed the very same problem several times on various computer programming competitions. It is equivalent to the well known problem "how to order the cards you are dealt with minimum number of moves"

Comment: Actually I think the correctness proof is quite simple: Consider a valid solution that moves only k items. It leaves untouched the other n-k items, so they must be already sorted. But the proposed algorithm finds the *longest* sorted subsequence, so it must leave at least n-k items untouched. Therefore, it moves at most k items.

Comment: @amit , Eyal I have added a detailed proof. Please have a look.

Comment: Regarding your proof: didn't you mean "Let's assume it is possible to reach B from A with less moves than **n-k**"?

Comment: Thanks, great answer! Would you mind adding some code or pseudocode to illustrate your concept?

Comment: @thg435 the pseudo code for the longest increasing sequence can be easily found online(there is even one version on the wiki article I link to). The algorithm I describe for reconstructing the solution is pretty straight forward I believe(actually this part of my answer is kind of a verbose pseudo-code solution I believe)

Comment: After looking at the pseudocode on Wikipedia a bit more carefully, I'm of the opinion that it's not *that* easy to translate into real code. I mean, what's "easy" of course depends on your skill with algorithms and programming; but there's a lot of indirection in that pseudocode, and the average programmer will probably need to sit with it for quite a while to really absorb what's happening.  This is fairly evident from the [discussion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Longest_increasing_subsequence) on that article.

Comment: Also, check out [this question, right here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992697/longest-increasing-subsequence).  The accepted answer is based on the Wikipedia algorithm, complete with long explanation.  There are also several other answers in various languages.  For even more, check out [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence).  The best Python implementation for the general case of randomly shuffled data is probably [this one](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/PADS/LongestIncreasingSubsequence.py).

Comment: @JohnY I agree that if someone is not familiar with the algorithm it will be hard to implement only from the code in wikipedia. Still I think explaining longest increasing subsequence should not be part of my answer

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: I have no problem with your answer (already upvoted it actually). My comments are mainly for other people who come across this answer and need further reading.

Answer (score 5):

If you regard your two lists as two strings -- e.g. the numbers are values in ASCII encoding -- then the problem is equivalent to that of finding the operations that allow you to transform the first string into the second one. The number of operations, in turn, is the Levenshtein or edit distance between the strings.

The [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) can be found by [using dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Iterative_with_full_matrix), storing in a matrix the distances between all prefixes of both strings, and then tracing back your steps to find at each row of the matrix which is the optimal operation (the one that has needed the least operations to arrive at it).

The longest increasing subsequence algorithm suggested by @IvayloStrandjev is related to the longest *common* subsequence problem, which in turn is related to the edit distance as an alternative metric that only allows insertion and substitution. Probably it is more performant in space, since it leverages the fact that one of the sequences has to be sorted; I just wanted to provide an alternative answer that I find easier to grasp.

Here is an implementation in Python of the full matrix Levenshtein algorithm, as described in the Wikipedia page linked above (originally found in a [1974 paper by Wagner and Fischer](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145%2F321796.321811)), where also a [proof of correctness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Proof_of_correctness) is supplied. Here we also store the **names** of the operations in a matrix of the same size as the operations **scores**, and we print the optimal operation after completing a row.

```
import argparse

import numpy as np


class Levenshtein(object):
    def __init__(self, string1, string2):
        self.string1 = string1
        self.string2 = string2
        self.scores_matrix = np.zeros(
            (len(self.string1) + 1, len(self.string2) + 1), dtype=np.int16)
        self.operations_matrix = np.empty_like(
            self.scores_matrix, dtype=(np.str_, 16))
        self.total_steps = 0

    def distance(self):
        m = len(self.string1) + 1
        n = len(self.string2) + 1
        for i in range(m):
            self.scores_matrix[i, 0] = i
        for j in range(n):
            self.scores_matrix[0, j] = j
        for j in range(1, n):
            for i in range(1, m):
                if self.string1[i - 1] == self.string2[j - 1]:
                    self.scores_matrix[i, j] = self.scores_matrix[i - 1, j - 1]
                    self.operations_matrix[i, j] = 'match'
                else:
                    self.scores_matrix[i, j] = self.select_operation(i, j)
                if j == n - 1:  # a row is complete
                    self.determine_best_op_and_print(i)
        return self.scores_matrix[m - 1, n - 1]

    def select_operation(self, i, j):
        possible_ops = ['delete', 'insert', 'substitute']
        ops_scores = [
            self.scores_matrix[i - 1, j] + 1,  # deletion
            self.scores_matrix[i, j - 1] + 1,  # insertion
            self.scores_matrix[i - 1, j - 1] + 1]  # substitution
        chosen_op = min(ops_scores)
        chosen_op_name = possible_ops[ops_scores.index(chosen_op)]
        self.operations_matrix[i, j] = chosen_op_name
        return chosen_op

    def determine_best_op_and_print(self, i):
        reversed_row = self.scores_matrix[i][::-1]
        reversed_pos_min = np.argmin(reversed_row)
        pos_min = len(self.scores_matrix[i]) - (reversed_pos_min + 1)
        best_op_name = self.operations_matrix[i, pos_min]
        if best_op_name != 'match':
            self.total_steps += 1
            print best_op_name, self.string1[i - 1], self.string2[pos_min - 1]


def parse_cli():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--list', nargs='*', required=True)
    return parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_cli()
    A = args.list
    S = sorted(A)
    lev = Levenshtein(A, S)
    dist = lev.distance()
    print "{} total steps were needed; edit distance is {}".format(
        lev.total_steps, dist)
```

Here is how to run the code with the examples you provide, and the output expected:

```
$ python levenshtein.py --list 8 1 2 3
substitute 8 1
1 total steps were needed; edit distance is 2

$ python levenshtein.py --list 9 1 2 3 0
substitute 9 0
substitute 0 9
2 total steps were needed; edit distance is 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends greatly on a few parameters of the problem that are not stated.  First, what moves are legal?  Neighboring-element swaps only?  Any arbitrary deletions and insertions?   Second, do you just need the number of moves or do you need a list of specific moves to perform?  These leads to different algorithms for this:

1. Neighboring swaps only - This is called inversion counting, if you only care about the minimal number.
2. Deletions, non-neighboring swaps, etc. - Levenshtein distance, mentioned previously, is a more general edit distance.  One trick about this is how you define your move-set.  Is moving an element 3 places over a single move or is it two moves (a deletion and an insertion)?

Inversion counts are pretty simple and can be done with some basic recursive algorithms.  You can use a merge-sort to find the inversion count between two lists by using one list to make a transformed version of the other, where the new elements are indices.  So if you have two sequences, you can do:

```
sequence = [seq2.index(element) for element in seq]
```

A simple straight-Python merge-sort implementation to count the inversions is:

```
if len(sequence) <= 1:
    return 0, sequence
else:
    firstHalf = sequence[:int(len(sequence)/2)]
    secondHalf = sequence[int(len(sequence)/2):]
    count1, firstHalf = mergeSortInversionCount(firstHalf)
    count2, secondHalf = mergeSortInversionCount(secondHalf)
    firstN = len(firstHalf)
    secondN = len(secondHalf)
    secondHalfEnd = secondN
    count3 = count1 + count2
    # Count the inversions in the merge
    # Uses a countdown through each sublist
    for i in xrange(firstN-1, -1, -1):
        x = firstHalf[i]
        inversionFound = False
        for j in xrange(secondHalfEnd-1,-1,-1):
            if x > secondHalf[j]:
                inversionFound = True
                break
        if inversionFound:
            secondHalfEnd = j+1
            count3 += j+1
    mergeList = firstHalf + secondHalf
    mergeList.sort()
    return count3, mergeList
```

This just divides the list in half and counts the inversions, sorting the list as it goes.  Merge sort is pretty efficient, algorithmically speaking (NlogN, though practically-speaking you could calculate it more quickly with some numpy matrices or by developing a minor adaptation to the C code for the underlying Python sorting algorithm.  Technically, given that this approach transforms any type of variables into numbers, it's basically reduced to just a list-sorting approach, so you can use other element-wise list sorts to do the same thing, so long as you track the count.

With any of these methods (inversion counting, Levenstein, etc.), you can log the moves, clearly.  Inversion counts log the swaps, logc noted a reasonable approach for logging some more general moves for Levenstein.  Personally, I tend to use inversion counts for this because they're fairly simple.  But it depends very much on what you want.  If you need more operations than two-element neighbor swaps, Levenstein is a clear choice.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a [Cycle Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_sort) and count the number of moves.  That's guaranteed to be the minimum number.