# Sorting an array using a storage

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have an array like this:

```
$a = [2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2];
```

I need to sort it, by using an external variable. But I need the following output:

```
$output = [
    [0, s],  // Move $a[0] to storage
    [5, 0],  // Move $a[5] to $[0]
    [s, 5],  // Move storage to $a[5]
    [4, s],  // Move $a[4] to storage
    [7, 4],  // Move $a[7] to $a[4]
    [s, 7]   // Move storage to $[7]
];
```

I need an algorithm to make an array, a delimitered string, or any kind of output, containing the steps to sort the array.

Mainly in PHP but I can implement it from any lang.

Comment: What is `s`? Is that supposed to be a character string `'s'`?

Comment: So, basically, you want to produce an assembly-language-like program that would sort the given array?

Comment: Write your own sort function, using an algorithm like bubble sort or quicksort. Whenever it swaps a pair of elements, it should add what it's doing to `$output`.

Comment: The 's' means as the comment tells. 's' means a variable like $s

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452645/finding-minimal-distance-between-unsorted-and-sorted-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fun if perhaps not that efficient idea:

Determine the count and sorted offset of each element:

```
$a = [2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2];
$count_and_offset = [1 => [3,0], 2 => [3,3], 3 => [2,6]]
```

Determine the permutation,

```
$a_permutation = [5, 2, 3, 4, 8, 1, 7, 6];
```

Enumerate the cycles (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation),

```
(1586)(2)(3)(4)(7)
```

Make a list (example is not zero-based),

```
[[6, s]
,[8, 6]
,[5, 8]
,[1, 5]
,[s, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use insertion sort (or do similar thing for other sorting algorithm like bubble sort or quicksort)

Pseudo code (which I took from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort))

```
for i ← 1 to length(A)
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
        swap A[j] and A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
```

So for the each swap step, you just need to print

```
[j , s]
[j - 1,j]
[s , j - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `array_map` : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-map.php (**old answer : `usort` : [http://php.net/manual/fr/function.usort.php](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.usort.php__)**) : create a custom function which make what you are looking for, and call it with array_map.

Comment: How would he use that array with `usort`? It doesn't define a comparison relationship between elements.

Comment: Please can you explain me this? How can usort help me?

Comment: Sorry, like I modifed, I was talking about `array_map`.